# Bad performace with slow query in Mysql. High query time in mysql-slow.log

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm tracking Mysql traffic and I faced with one Query, with a high number of entries, wasting a lof of time each transaction.
Here is an example from mysql-slow.log:

```
  # Time: 190301  0:00:36
  # User@Host: localhost []
  # Query_time: 3.318860  Lock_time: 0.000077 Rows_sent: 1  
  Rows_examined: 4913
  SET timestamp=1551394836;

SELECT * 
FROM `table_tmp`
WHERE `ns` = '123456'
  AND `ws` = '-' 
  AND `id` > (
    SELECT MAX(`id`) 
    FROM `table_tmp` 
    WHERE `ns` = '123456' AND `ws` != '-' 
    ORDER BY `id` DESC) 
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

And here is EXPLAIN instruction:

[image]

1. 'table_tmp' has about 900k rows.
2. 'table_tmp' has indexes in 'ns', 'id' (auto increment, primary)
3. What I need to get is the last row when "ws" was != '-'. We can say that, I seek into databse the moment with "ws" != '-', and then I pick up the next "id", the upper row.
4. There are many different "ns".

AS you can see it takes between 3 seconds, sometimes 2 seconds, and the working is quite often, so, It appears a lot in mysql-slow.log.
Do you see something I can change? I tried to think about Query, changing indexes... but nothing from my side.

Thanks a lot,
Regards!

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is useless. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table_tmp t
WHERE t.ns = 123456 AND  -- it looks like a number so I assume it is
      t.ws = '-' AND
      t.id > (SELECT MAX(t2.id) 
              FROM table_tmp t2
              WHERE t2.ns = t.ns AND t2.ws <> '-' 
             ) 
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

I would recommend an index on `table_tmp(ns, ws, id)`.  This is a composite index with three columns.

Comment: you mean a triple index? Not single indexes in ns, ws and id. One index in these 3 columns, right?

Comment: @vincenzorochetta . . . I've never heard the term "triple index".  This is an index with three columns.

Comment: I meant that. sorry for the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The following index could improve the performance:

```
create index ix1 on table_tmp (ns, ws, id);
```

If still slow, this next index can improve performance further:

```
create index ix2 on table_tmp (id, ns, ws);
```